# How to use the menu bar in terminal emacs?

Tags: terminal-emacs, menu-bar

I am using `emacs` on the remote server, and I have no idea how to click on options in the menu bar across the top in this context.

Here is a screen capture:

[image: Screenshof emacs showing the menu bar with entries like "File", "Edit", "Options", "Buffers" etc.]

For example, I want to click some options under "File" in the menu bar (on the top), how can I do that?

Comment: Here is a link to the documentation regarding using the menu-bar in the terminal:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Menu-Bar.html

Comment: Besides using the mouse (and yes, that is possible with a terminal), library [**LaCarte**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LaCarte) lets you use the keyboard with completion.  If you also use [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you can complete against any parts of the menu hierarchy directly, including using regexp matching and fuzzy matching.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't think the mouse really works when running in the terminal, so you cannot actually click. But to open the menus press `F10` (or `fn-F10` depending on your keyboard settings).

Answer (score 9):

If you're intent on using the mouse, you can use a subset of mouse click functionality if your terminal is compatible with `xterm`.  To do so, enable `xterm-mouse-mode`.

Source: [manual page on "Using a Mouse in Text Terminals"](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text_002dOnly-Mouse.html).

However, as @Ista's answer and @lawlist's comment suggest, you can use the keyboard to access the menu bar.  That's probably a better option long-term, as you'll speed up when going keyboard-only.